# Customizing Chatter Pages/Emails

Tags: email, chatter, chatter-groups

We've implemented a custom chatter UI page, but would like to continue to use the standard notifications for posts. The problem is that these emails including a link to the standard UI chatter page.

Has anyone found a way to either customize the link on the page or override the page that it links to?

Are there any other feasible workarounds without implementing a third-part mass mail app? - the groups are too big for standard mass emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the chatter UI page using chatter connect API. 
Here is the dreamforce video which walks you thru the customization of chatter UI using connect API `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03FGYPYtpW4`

Edit --

I dont think we can change the links in Chatter email notifications,But as a Workaround you can ask your community users to change their Chatter Email settings to stop receiving the notifications.Below is the link which provides complete details of how to implement it
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_email_notify.htm&language=en_US&type=0&release=204.17

Comment: It seems that this is just creating a whole new interface, while losing a lot of the existing functionality (If they had turned emails on, it seems that they would have the same problem that it would link them to the standard page.) I don't have any issue creating a page with the feeds, my problem is that I can't seem to use that with existing email functionality, which is important.

Comment: Edited my answer.